# My Mac keeps broadcasting UDP packets to 255.255.255.255:2008

Tags: mac, networking, spam-prevention, udp

The source port changes rapidly, from 49xxx to 6xxxx. I tried to use lsof -i udp, and see there's process named mDNSRespo which holds a lot of udp sockets. However, none of these sockets' ports are of source ports of sockets broadcasting packets.

Is there a utility to find out which process is doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Found this same issue today, check to see if "Remote Mouse" is installed, that was the culprit on my network.

Comment: This seems like a potentially helpful, albeit not ideal, answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29), and its basically throwing out broadcasts to advertise its presence. You can use good old [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat), either in cli or through [network utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Utility) to determine this. If you're using cli, also consider using grep to filter through the results, and the -b switch to display the binary's name - I'd use something like `netstat -abn | grep 255.255.255.255` - which if i recall should show all connections, and list the binaries and ip addresses, and greps for that ip address.

Comment: I stopped Bonjour, and it still keeps broadcasting..

Comment: What does netstat say?

Comment: Unlike NetBIOS, Bonjour exclusively uses multicasts, not broadcasts.